# Optimizing a circle’s area given strange initial conditions

Tags: optimization, area

Given point $(x, y)$, $0 \lt x \lt 1$ & $0 \lt y \lt 1$, define a function     $F(x, y)$ that does the following:

Returns the area of the largest circle that fits within the unit square (assuming the unit square's bottom left corner is at the origin on a coordinate plane) and does not touch the largest circle centred around $(x, y)$ that fits within the unit square. To explain that more clearly, look at this heuristic:

Slight edit to question: ignore cases where the largest possible circle is not tangent to the initial circle because all of those are trivial (radius is simply 0.5)

- find the largest possible circle that is centered at $(x, y)$ and stays within the unit square. By “stays within” I mean the square can be tangent to the circle, but the circle may not exceed the unit square.
- find the largest circle that stays within the unit square (same definition of “stays within” applies) and does not overlap the first circle (the circles may be tangent to each other but not overlap)
- return the area of the second circle

Good news - I’ve solved it! Once I took the approach that @RossMillikan suggested, I realized that you can find the largest circle by starting in the top right corner and expanding the circle until it is tangent to the first circle

I completely forgot to post my solution earlier, but here it is:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/amfklduy6m

I did this a while back so I forget my exact though process, but if someone is really interested I can go back through it all and explain it

Comment: What is your question? How to compute $F(x,y)$?

Comment: You'll get more help if you show your efforts and doubts so far.

Comment: Yes, find the function F(x, y) which works for any x & y within the domain and range specified (basically within the unit square) and returns the correct area

Comment: @NoahK Yes, in the top right there should be a button that looks like an arrow coming out of a square. Click that and copy the link and paste it here.

Comment: You can assume that $0 \le x \le y \le \frac 12$ by renaming the variables and subtracting them from $1$ is necessary.  That puts $(x,y)$ inside a triangle that is $\frac 18$ of the square.  The first circle is then of radius $x$, so if our coordinates are $(x',y')$  its equation is $(x'-x)^2+(y'-y)^2=x^2$.  Now you need to find the circle that is tangent to this circle and the right and top sides of the square.

Comment: @RossMillikan I understand what you mean by subtracting them from 1, as (0.4, 0.6) returns the same answer as (0.4, 0.4) , and I follow what you wrote about the circle equation, but I'm not sure what you mean by fitting all points into a triangle. How would you fit the points (0.4, 0.4) into a triangle 1/8 the size? I understand how everything can be put into a square 1/4 the size because there is 4 way symmetry, but I'm having trouble understanding the triangle bit.

Comment: @kccu thank you, I've added the link. I did most of that freshman year of high school, so I understand if it is underwhelming for you all

Comment: The point $(0.4,0.4)$ is in the triangle.  The triangle has corners $(0,0), (0,\frac 12), (\frac 12,\frac 12)$.  The circle around it is not in the triangle, but that is OK.  I just picked a standard position to work with because it gives you a unique first circle without a bunch of if statements to resolve which sides the first circle is tangent to.  My position makes sure it is tangent to the left side of the square, so the radius is $y$ (a correction from my previous comment).

Comment: @RossMillikan I understand now - that’s very clever

Comment: @RossMillikan thanks a ton for pointing that out - I was able to solve it p easily with the problem reduced to that. You’re a real one for that.

Comment: @NoahK:  you should write up your solution as an answer.  The FAQ encourages that if you solve your own problem.  It will also force you to make sure you really understand it.  After a delay (2 days?) you will be able to accept it.